# Require.js lazy loading remote url

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I have a file called moment.js on my local file system and loading it as follows with require.js works:

```
initialize: function() {

    require(['moment'], function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
}
```

However, if I do:

```
initialize: function() {

    require(['http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js'], function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
}
```

data comes back undefined. Why is this? and how do I dynamically include remote modules at runtime?

Comment: nope. just waits then logs data as undefined.

Answer (score 11):

I noticed that the code you are trying to load hardcodes the module name as `moment` so configure RequireJS on the spot so that you can require with the same name:

```
initialize: function() {

    require.config({
        paths: { moment: 'http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min' }
    });

    require(['moment'], function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think url for moment should be without filename extension i.e. it should look like as follows:
moment:'http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min'

Answer (score -2):

If you need to load a module both locally AND from a remote URL, you should **name** the module when **defining** it and add an "alias" module which is named like the URL, with both modules defined inside the **same file**.

Example:

```
    //define a module NAMED "moment" using the first optional name paramter
    define("moment", ["require"], function (require) { 
       /*module code goes here*/
   });

    //alias module to use when lazy loading from URL
    define("http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js", ["require"], function (require) {
       return require("moment");//returns original module
   });
```

You can read more about this in a blog post I wrote [here](http://m6s.blogspot.co.il/2014/11/lazy-load-requirejs-modules-from-remote_4.html).